# Sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 — probably unsupported type как исправить?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite, telebot

Подскажите,как исправить, эту ошибку?

```
in start
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO usermember(user_id,username) VALUES(?,?)", (user_id,username))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Ругается на эту строку

```html
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO usermember(user_id,username) VALUES(?,?)", (user_id,username))
```

Нужно чтобы в файл users.db записывался id пользователя и ник, который человек создал, для телеграм,
но поля пустые, подскажите как это исправить, писал код с видео, но там только одно поле прописывалось user_id.

Вот весь код

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import connect
import cursor as cursor
import telebot

API_TOKEN = 'moy_token'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    connect = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usermember ( 
    user_id INTEGER,
    username TEXT
    )""")

    connect.commit()

    user_id = ["message.from_user.id"]
    username = ["message.chat.username"]
    print(type(user_id))
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO usermember(user_id,username) VALUES(?,?)", (user_id,username))
    connect.commit()

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Все варианты, что я делал, чтобы определить user_id и username чтобы верно они прописались в бд.

```
#user_id = ["message.user.id"]
#user_id = ["message.chat.user.id"]
user_id = ["message.from_user.id"]
username = ["message.from_user.username"]
username = ["message.chat.username"]
#username = ["message.chat.username"]
#username = ["message.chat.user_username"]
#username = ["message.user_username"]
#username = ["message.user.username"]
#username = ["message.from_user.username"]
#username = ["message.chat.username"]
```

**это все варианты, что я делал, так как, думал что может я неверно прописал, user_id и username и возможно поэтому ошибка, хотя ругается на другую строку, но они же, взаимосвязаны между собой.**

Comment: @MaxU, а точно дубликат? Вроде тут другой косяк?

Comment: @Qwertiy, в ответе по ссылке описано (с примерами) как это правильно делать )

Comment: @MaxU, согласен. Просто тут косяк в коде странный)

Comment: @Qwertiy, с этим не поспоришь )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> user_id = ["message.from_user.id"]
> username = ["message.chat.username"]
> ```

```
user_id = message.from_user.id
username = message.chat.username
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, ошибок нет, все записалось в базу, мой ид и мой ник.

Comment: Ответ прими нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: Нажал на галочку, думаю что верно понял Вас.