# Не работает условие WHERE в SQLite запросе

Tags: python, база-данных, бот, aiogram, sqlite3

Пишу телеграм-бота, возникла надобность сделать клавиатуру ReplyKeyboardMarkup, где значения кнопок будут браться из базы данных SQLite. Написал соответствующую функцию:

```
async def cmd_abit_filters_region(message: types.Message, state = FSMContext):
async with state.proxy() as abit_filter:
    abit_filter['region'] = message.text[1:]
region_pressed = "('" + message.text[1:] + "',)"
region_pressed = message.text[1:]
with open('''C:/Users/vvvpe/Desktop/Connect/Data/filters.txt''', 'a') as filters:
    filters.write('''\n["%s", ''' % str(abit_filter['region']))

universities_list = []
for value in cur.execute(f'''SELECT university FROM vlnt_table WHERE region = ?''', [region_pressed]):
    current_value = str(value)
    current_value = current_value.replace('(', '')
    current_value = current_value.replace(')', '')
    current_value = current_value.replace("'", "")
    current_value = current_value.replace(',', '')
    print(current_value)
    universities_list.append(current_value)
base.commit()
universities_set = list(set(universities_list))
universities_set = universities_list
print(universities_set)
kb_universities = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
for i in universities_set:
    kb_universities.add(f"Университет {i}")

await FSMFilters.next()
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выберите интересующий вас вуз', reply_markup=kb_universities)
```

Никаких трейсов нет. Просто не включается клавиатура, как будто в цикле for курсор не находит в базе соответствия. Я пробовал выводить значения из базы, выдаётся такое: ('Москва',), ('Санкт-Петербург',) - с запятыми и скобками, поэтому я пытался к переменной region_pressed эти знаки вручную прикрутить. Пробовал и без этого костыля - не работает, ошибок не выдаёт((( Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Что приходит в `message.text[1:]` ? Вы пишете `пробовал выводить значения из базы, выдаётся такое` - какой запрос это выдавал?

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA , это я не выводил. Попробовал - выводит егион Москва, егион Санкт-Петербург. Сейчас попробую изменить срез, вы натолкнули меня на эту мысль, спасибо!

Comment: Это нечестно, так задавать вопросы:-) Мне в голову не пришло, что вы не проверили, что у вас в `message.text[1:]` находится, а сразу взялись его преобразовывать, "прикручивая" скобки и т.д.:-) Впрочем, информацию из моего ответа всё равно советую учесть.

Comment: @Сергей , все работает!! спасибо еще раз, извините, если что не так

Comment: Я немного шучу. Но комментарий мой последний выше и ко мне и к вам относится на будущее:-) - проверять начинать с самого простого и последовательно.

Comment: что в конечном счете изменили-то относительно начального текста?

Comment: @Сергей, прикрутил кортеж по вашему совету, изменил срез на [7:], это пропуск слова Регион и пробела после него, чтобы осталось только само название города

Comment: а [region_pressed] - так и остался в квадратных скобках?

Comment: @Сергей, без скобок, вообще без знаков, просто region_pressed в запросе

Comment: OK, cпасибо, т.е. я оба этих случая правильно поймал. Тогда ответ оставлю, как есть. Плюсанул вопрос, интересно было:-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Это же кортежи - их `execute` принимает. Тогда рекомендация на исправление вместо "эти знаки вручную прикрутить":

```
region_pressed = (message.text[1:],)
```

Тут тип - кортеж, как видим из `type (region_pressed)`.

А у вас строка получалась:

```
region_pressed = "('" + message_text[1:] + "',)"
```

Мне не проверить - нет БД, подкрутите по ситуации.

И, как понимаю, писать надо в запросах не `[region_pressed]`, а просто `region_pressed`. Вот похожий случай:
[Sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 — probably unsupported type как исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1380850/sqlite3-interfaceerror-error-binding-parameter-0-probably-unsupported-type-%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: не работает, попробовал

Comment: File "C:\Users\vvvpe\Desktop\Connect\handlers\General.py", line 150, in cmd_abit_filters_region
    for value in cur.execute(f'''SELECT university FROM vlnt_table WHERE region = ?''', [region_pressed]):
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: исправил. пробуйте так. И у вас там две строки с `region_pressed` почему-то. первая не нужна, вторую поменять на строку из ответа.

Comment: та же ошибка вылетает

Comment: исправил с двумя region_pressed, да

Comment: Дальше тогда не помогу, нет БД, а sqlLite  не знаю, но преобразовавать точно надо, как я написал (добавил к ответу описание разницы).

Comment: Ну как, помогло изменение запроса на просто `region_pressed`?

Comment: не вышло(( Спасибо, что пытались помочь!